# : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python

пытаюсь сделать диалоговую прграмму 
вот код :

```
with open([r'C:\Users\максим\Desktop\t800\t800.txt']) as f:
     lines = [x.rstrip() for x in f.readlines()]
     print(lines[lines.index(input())+1])
```

выдаёт ошибку- TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
буду безумно благодарен ,кто поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(r'C:\Users\максим\Desktop\t800\t800.txt') as f:
```

Если он не хочет list, уберите `[]`

Comment: спасибо большое